# Selenium python WebDriver. Search text inside a div

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I need to click on the checkbox inside the div, but first I need to check the text near the checkbox and if a text is a true click on the checkbox.

[image]

Comment: please provide code instead of images if not really necessary. Further, could you maybe point out what you tried so far?

Comment: Please add html code instead image and code with error you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

You can first extract the text from the source page then check whether it is there or not then click

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select `checkbox` based on text so it is very simple. You can pass required text in below `xpath` and locate `checkbox`.

```
text = "Google Play"

//a[.="+ text +"]/..//input
```

This way whatever text you will pass either `Google play` or `iTunes` it will locate checkbox based on given `text`